# PowerShell - last report and sync time values of WSUS servers do not match when PowerShell is used

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, poshwsus

I use PoshWSUS 2.3.1.6

When I go to "Update Services" in Windows 10 and connect to my WSUS Server, I see many workstations in the server with different `LastStatusReport` and `LastContact` dates as shown with two examples below. Please note that my local, WSUS server and all the workstations are configured to the same Time Zone: `Eastern Standard Time (UTC-05:00)`

[image]

My aim is to get those dates via PowerShell and export to CSV. The code I use for this:

```
& Get-PoshWSUSClient | select @{name="Computer";expression={$_.FullDomainName}},@{name="Last Status Report";expression={$_.LastReportedStatusTime}}, @{name="Last Contact";expression={$_.LastSyncTime}} | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -append $FileOutput
```

This returns non-consistent as the time values returned are 4 hours ahead. The workstations from the picture are exported like:

```
590   10/16/2019 01:40   10/16/2019 04:40
413   9/26/1019  05:38   10/16/2019 05:56
```

So, what should be the reason it happening? Is it possible to add Time Zone info to the time value? Is it possible to cast the value to datetime by using Time Zone info? I've tried below, still same result.

```
Get-pswsusclient | select @{name="Computer";expression={$_.FullDomainName}},@{name="LastReportedStatusTime";expression={[datetime]$_.LastReportedStatusTime}}, @{name="LastSyncTime";expression={[datetime]$_.LastSyncTime}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you on Daylight Saving Time? Looks like the dates returned are in UTC. Can you check the `.Kind` property? Try `ToLocalTime()`

Comment: @Theo ToLocalTime() worked!! Thank you. Add an answer, I'll select as correct answer

Comment: I'm on mobile now, so the answer will be short I'm afraid ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the dates returned are in UTC. You could check the `.Kind` property.

```
ToLocalTime()
```

Should help.